# Solving cryptarithmetic problems

Tags: cryptarithm

I was recently trying to solve cryptarithmetic problems like:

```
       F Y H
     * E W T
     -------- 
     Z E T F
   E K Z Z
 Y Z T X
 ------------
 Y F Y W E F
```

But I am failing repeatedly to get the hang of such problems.I start solving problems but then I cannot get the intuition of such problems.How should I practise to master them?Any good resources in this regard?

Comment: Maybe you're just not cut out for solving cryptarithms. I understand it's quite possible to win a Fields medal without being able to do cryptarithms.

Comment: @GerryMyerson,well I may not be cut out for the task.But some alternative ways might help me in clarifying the concept.Different people understand things differently.So can you suggest resources which explain this in a different way?

Comment: I'm not familiar with any book, or any chapter in any book, specifically aimed at improving facility with cryptarithms. The only method I know for doing them is trial-and-error together with clever use of every fact you know about digits and multiplication. You might enjoy the section on "Arithmetical Restorations" in Ball and Coxeter, Mathematical Recreations and Essays, or the section "Cryptarithmetic" in Kraitchik, Mathematical Recreations. Or maybe just time "Cryptarithms" into Google, and see what comes up.

Comment: The particular example you have posted seems to be an Elitmus Aptitude Question, whatever that means: http://www.m4maths.com/34221-F-Y-H-E-W-T-Z-E-T-F-E-K-Z-Z-Y-Z-T-X-Y-F.html

Comment: Now posted to (but closed on) MO, without linking either post to the other. Shame on you. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/177896/solving-cryptarithmetic-problems

Comment: MR0934570 (89d:00004), Eiss, Harry Edwin, Dictionary of mathematical games, puzzles, and amusements. Greenwood Press, Westport, CT, 1988. xvi+279 pp. ISBN: 0-313-24714-5 has an essay on cryptarithms.

Comment: So, have you had a look at any of the resources I have mentioned?

Comment: @GerryMyerson,well I would look into them soon as currently these resources are not available easily,in the area which I reside.

Comment: @GerryMyerson,are any of these available online or any other good resource?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not going to tie your shoelaces for you. I found you some possible resources; you can do the search to see whether they are online. And if you can't find them online, do they have libraries where you live?

Answer (score -1):

```
     8 4 6
    *5 7 3
  ----------
   2 5 3 8
 5 9 2 2
```

4 2 3 0

---

4 8 4 7 5 8

---

where
F=8,
Y=4
H=6
E=5
W=7
T=3
Z=2
K=9
X=0